# keep the keystore while changing computer

Tags: android, updates, keystore, signing

So I have an app on the play store and I'm changing my computer.

I'm new to this and I needed to ask someone so here it is:

In order to keep updating my app from the new computer, I only need to keep the keytore file (the one I created on the old computer) no other files/procedures are needed right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  I did this before. I used them on windows and then when i transferred to Mac.  Keeping the keystore file (private key) is essential to updating your work on google play. It identifies who you are and unless your a great hacker if you lose it you'll have to start all over with a new page on the play store. Its essential to back them up. I store them on a cloud and use them whenever i need it.

Comment: Awesome, so all I need to keep is the keystore file ?

Comment: yes!. and remember if you lose that file, kiss your google play listing good bye.