# EAS Keystore Transfer to New Mac

Tags: keystore

If I have allows EAS Cli to automatically generate a keystore for my mobile app, how do I ensure that I can still use this keystore from another Mac?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keep the keystore while changing computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609838/keep-the-keystore-while-changing-computer)